# Problem with balloon tips

Tags: c#, mvvm, notifyicon, popup-balloons

HI,

I create balloon tips all over our application. My problem is that all of the balloon tips stay on the task-bar and needs to be hovered over for them to disappear.

```
        public static bool SetBalloonTip(string balloonTipTitle, string balloonTipText, ToolTipIcon balloonTipIcon)
    {
        bool result = false;
        NotifyIcon notifyIcon;

        try
        {
            notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();

            notifyIcon.Icon = SystemIcons.Information;
            notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = balloonTipTitle;
            notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = balloonTipText;
            notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = balloonTipIcon;

            notifyIcon.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(30000);

            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

My question is, how do i make the notify icon disappear after it has been shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

first:

```
private static System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
```

Second:

```
public static bool SetBalloonTip(string balloonTipTitle, string balloonTipText, ToolTipIcon balloonTipIcon)
    {
        bool result = false;
        NotifyIcon notifyIcon;

        try
        {
            if (components == null)
            {
                components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            }

            notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon(components);

            notifyIcon.Icon = SystemIcons.Information;
            notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = balloonTipTitle;
            notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = balloonTipText;
            notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = balloonTipIcon;

            notifyIcon.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(30000);

            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Third:

```
        public static void DisposeOfBallonTips(bool disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            // Clean up any components being used.
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (components != null)
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Calling `DisposeOfBallonTips` when i want to clean up all `NotifyIcons`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you displying more than one balloon at a time?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160064.aspx):

> Only one balloon tip can display on the taskbar at a time. Attempting to display a balloon tip when one is currently displayed on the taskbar causes the timeout value to be ignored.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160064.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm mostly guessing but try this

add an event handler like this and see if it helps.

```
     ...
     ... 
     notifyIcon.BalloonTipClosed += new EventHandler(notifyIcon_BalloonTipClosed);
     notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(30000);
     ...
}



static void notifyIcon_BalloonTipClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((NotifyIcon) sender).Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I think that event is only raised when a user actively closes the balloon.